# Posting Array of objects along with image field in posman form-data

Tags: node.js, api, postman

i am trying to post array  of objects with postman in form-data(also want to upload image) but on backend i am only recieving one index with object in string format.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In XHR , the data is passed in String format, thus when it is received at the server, you have to use `JSON.parse` to convert back `string` to `object or array`.
You cannot pass array or object directly in XHR post method.

use `JSON.stringify()` for converting `data` to `string` :

```js
JSON.stringify(data)
```

For retrieving data at server

use `JSON.parse()` for converting `string` to `data` :

```js
JSON.parse(data)
```

Comment: i already tried it i am getting string not Array '[{"id":"5f44594e8dfdd506a025ccdf","name":"Account Manager"}]'

Comment: Yes, you need to parse it like:  `JSON.parse(datastring)`

Comment: In Postman? i want to send this field of roles through postman? how to use JSON.parse(arr) in postman

Answer (score 0):

Yea roles should not have the square brackets, instead they should be wrapped around the array you are passing in. Here's an example with ExpressJS I just put together.
Code:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-Parser");
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post("/", function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send("Success");
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Running on port 3000");
});
```

JSON object:

```
{
    "testArray": [
        {
            "firstName": "Joe",
            "lastName": "Smith",
            "age": 51
        },
        {
            "firstName": "James",
            "lastName": "Smith",
            "age": 21
        }
    ]
}
```

result from `console.log(req.body)`

```
{
  testArray: [
    { firstName: 'Joe', lastName: 'Smith', age: 51 },
    { firstName: 'James', lastName: 'Smith', age: 21 }
  ]
}
```

Not sure what framework you are using for developing your API but ExpressJS is easy and very well documented.

Comment: its not about express or node my target is to send array of objects in postman in formdata i can do this row but i also want to upload photo

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add lots of fields with same name in Postman form-data `key-value` input and it will turn them to an array

```js
input:1
input:2
input:3
file:some-file

>> in server you will have
{
  input:[1,2,3],
  file:some-file
}
```